# Why doesn't my to_string() work?

Tags: c++, string

I am doing a BigInt implementation and for one of my constructors, I'm required to take in an int value and basically convert it to a string, and then take each character and save it into a node of a linked list.

My struct Digit Node is a doubly linked list with value 'char digit'. My class BigInt has two private member variables head and tail. (which are pointers to DigitNode).

I am getting this error:  error: call of overloaded ‘to_string(int&)’ is ambiguous

My file headers:

```
#include <iosfwd>
#include <iostream>
#include "bigint.h"


using namespace std;
```

My constructor:

```
BigInt::BigInt(int i) // new value equals value of int (also a default ctor)
{ 
  string num = to_string(i);
  DigitNode *ptr = new DigitNode;
  DigitNode *temp;
  ptr->prev = NULL;
  this->head = ptr;
  if (num[0] == '-' || num[0] == '+') ptr->digit = num[0];
  else ptr->digit = num[0] - '0';
  for (int i = 1; num[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {      
      ptr->next = new DigitNode;
      temp = ptr;
      ptr = ptr->next;
      ptr->digit = num[i] - '0';
      ptr->prev = temp;
    }
  ptr->next = NULL;
  this->tail = ptr;

}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What compiler are you using? MSVC?

Comment: Is this your own implementation of `to_string` or the one included in the standard library?

Comment: Im using g++. And I'm trying to use the standard library implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I would have to guess you are using VC 2010, the problem is VC2010 only provides overloads for `long`, `long long`, `long double`, `unsigned long`. `int` is not included. You need to use a type compliant instead:

`static_cast<long long>(i)`

that line would become

```
string num = to_string(static_cast<long long>(i));
```